# CSS margins capturing click events, in Chrome/Windows only

Tags: css, wordpress

I've got a generic Wordpress blog, with a generic theme. I've found that in Chrome on Windows, maximizing the browser window causes parts of the page to become disabled - no mouseover events, no click events, nothing.

Turns out that the margin area of the div next door is capturing the clicks.  Only happens on Chrome (30 or 31) on Windows (Vista or 7) and only when the window is maximized.

Try it at https://content.neit.edu/courseware/201410nur370/
Screencast showing how to reproduce steps is at https://www.kaltura.com/index.php/extwidget/openGraph/wid/1_nvbbym8w

If you add ?debug to the URL, it'll display an alert showing the target element that was clicked.

I'm thinking this is a browser rendering bug, but is there something I'm not seeing in the CSS that's contributing to the problem?   Seems that margins capturing click events should be impossible, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the wrapping of `#content` with `#primary`: because `#primary` has a width of 100% and is floated, it is covering up `#secondary`.

You'll need to tweak the values, but this should get you close:

```
.left-sidebar #primary {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: 75%;
}
.left-sidebar #content {
   margin: 0 7.6% 0 0;
   width: 90%;
}
```

Think of two containers: `primary` and `secondary`.  Use those containers to do your layout, then you can let the contents take up 100% of their parents' width, apply your padding, etc. to the children.

I'll also note that in Chrome 31 and canary on Windows, the area is covered up (clicks occur on `#primary`) regardless of the window size.

Comment: That did it - thank you. Didn't expect the browser/platform difference on this one, but your solution fixed it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem! On initial thought, the Chrome behavior is what I would expect with that CSS.  I'm not sure if this is a chrome or [other browser here] bug.  I'd have to look at specs.